# Chrome extension in javascript and link in popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I'm currently devlopping an add-on to inform people when the streamer is live. The problem is that my link to the live doesn't work correctly (we have the obligation to open it in new tab (mollet click)).

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"version" :"1.0",
"name" : "extension chrome",
"description" : "Crystal_forest live",
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup" :"Anya.html",
    "default_icon" : { "16" : "Icon_rouge.png"}
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"]
}
}
```

my Anya.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titre de la page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='desc'>Off!</p>
        <a href="https:/twitter.com">
            <img src="logo.png">
        </a>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my background.js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", "IHideTheLink", true);
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if (xhr.readyState == 4){
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (data["time_online"] != -1){
            $("#desc").html("Online! :3");
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                path: "Icon_vert.png"
            })
        }
     }
 }
 xhr.send();
```

Can you help me find why is my link not working properly?

Comment: add `target="_blank"` before `href` in your `<a>` tag.

Comment: @wOxxOm - or after :p

Comment: will try this ty guys!